# Send google analytics event with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics

I am trying to send a google analytics through a controller, I searched the web and got to a point where I think the event should be sent but isn't.

I have a url_share_controller.rb that contains this :

```
  def create
    emails_count = EmailExtractor.new(input: share_params[:emails]).emails.length

    @sharer = URLSharer.new(
      user: current_user,
      type: 'invite',
      url: Rails.application.secrets.academos_public_website_mentee_landing,
      emails: share_params[:emails],
      message: share_params[:message]
    )

    if @sharer.share!
      google_analytics_event(category: 'teacher-service', action: 'send', label: 'share-url', value: emails_count)
      head :no_content
    else
      google_analytics_event(category: 'teacher-service', action: 'error', label: 'share-url', value: emails_count)
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

In my application.rb I have this method where the event output is as intended:

```
  def google_analytics_event(category:, action:, label:, value:)
    flash.now[:event] =  "<script>ga('send', 'event', '#{category}', '#{action}', '#{label}', '#{value}')</script>".html_safe
  end
```

But I see no events in my google analytics account. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you waiting the usual 24 hours before checking your standard reports? You might also want to verify in Real-Time (a bit unreliable sometimes), or try installing Chrome GA Debugger to verify your hits in the dev console. Also, I'm not sure how the `'#{category}`, `'#{action}`, etc. parameters will be evaluated...

Comment: I'm checking the realtime and the firefox go debugger.

Comment: Ruling out the obvious, did you make sure you are not filtering out your own visits?

Comment: I'm not, I can see both my browsers on the pages.

Comment: Do I need to set something special to be able to use flash.now[:event] ?

Comment: Sorry, Rails is not familiar with me :) I was checking that the GA bits were all good.

Comment: Ok, thanks though.

Comment: `head :no_content` means that your action isn't returning a html page, but just a empty respond with a status code `200 ok`. Where do you expect the javascript code to be rendered, when there is no html document?

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Sorry for asking obvious questions, I'm a beginner working on an existing website. I'll go check how to trigger js from a controller now.